# Add support for UEFI

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

Trying to install Linux last night, but cannot boot with UEFI. Please add support for UEFi.

I created bootable using unetbootin, pendrivelinux UEFI, but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing in UEFI mode](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/724/installing-in-uefi-mode)

Comment: Elementary already supports UEFI. With [Unetbootin](https://elementary.io/es/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium) you should be able to create a bootable usb.  Please check your bios settings to be sure you are using the correct boot options. If you need more help please create a new question explaining your problem